# Writing @app.after_request function in file different from app creation

Tags: python, flask

I create app in one file but want to write an after_request in another

app.py

```py
app = create_app()
```

my_blueprint.py

```py
@app.after_request
def my_after_request_function():
  ...
```

I want to do this because in this case it makes sense to group this function in this blueprint file. Is there a way to make this work?

I couldn't really think of anything to do that work. I obviously could just write this function within app.py, but I'm trying to keep the code organized by keeping everything into separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new blueprint object in my_blueprint.py file and register it in app as follows:

my_blueprint.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

after_request = Blueprint('after_request', __name__)

@after_request.after_request
def my_after_request_function():
  ...
```

main.py

```
from my_blueprint import after_request
app = create_app()
app.register_blueprint(after_request)
```